# AttributeError : 'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I am new to both opencv and python and i am trying to run Face Recognition code given [here](https://github.com/bytefish/facerec/blob/d866ef68ffe96de11e164493d29cc4b124cf7844/py/apps/videofacerec/simple_videofacerec.py).i have installed all the dependencies yet it is throwing the same problem "AttributeError : 'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'shape' ".
I unable to solve it.

[image: Problem in Output.]

Comment: Could you be more specific on the line of code it is giving you the error message? With this little information, if I had to make a guess the first thing that pops into my mind is that maybe you are not properly reading the image, could you verify the value of  frame here `ret, frame = self.cam.read()`?

Answer (score 2):

From the stack trace it seems that your frame variable is Null. You will need to look at the code and figure out why. Or paste the code or provide a link so that others can help you.